# How to convert 2 object into single one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

i've got 2 objects

```
const size = shoppingCart.map((el) => ({size: el.size}));
```

The first one is filteredProducts list:

```
    const filteredProducts = [
    {
        description: "Material: 100% cotton\nCare instructions: Do not tumble dry, machine wash at 30 ° C, machine wash on gentle cycle",
        id: "80005397",
        image: {url: 'h,ttps://www.datocms-assets.com/59095/1638273249-spodnie.png'},
        price: 32.8,
        title: " Pier One Cargo"
    }
]
```

And second one that is selected size:

```
  const selectedSize = [
    {
        size: 'L'
    }
]
```

I have to combine this 2 objects into single one like this:

```
    const filteredProducts = [
    {
        description: "Material: 100% cotton\nCare instructions: Do not tumble dry, machine wash at 30 ° C, machine wash on gentle cycle",
        id: "80005397",
        image: {url: 'h,ttps://www.datocms-assets.com/59095/1638273249-spodnie.png'},
        price: 32.8,
        title: " Pier One Cargo",
        size: 'L'
    }
]
```

Comment: `filteredProducts.size = selectedSize.size` ??

Comment: You are probably looking for `Object.assign`

Comment: both of the arrays have always the same length?

Comment: Yeah, its always same length

Comment: the question is unclear. Are both arrays always the same size? Or do these arrays contain just one object each that you want to merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map() function and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const filteredProductsWithSize = filteredProducts.map((product, i) => ({
    ...product,
    ...selectedSize[i]
}));
```